# Low 'Burst Rate' from SATA drive in HDTune?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, sata, benchmarking

I recently upgraded my laptop's v slow hard drive to a seagate momentus 7200.  Everything is working fine, but I'm a bit confused by these benchmark results:

[image: Seagate Momentus 250 7200 benchmark]

**The burst rate is significantly less than the Maximim transfer rate, and not much higher than the normal minimum (if you ignore the spikes).  What's going on here?**

On the HDtune website it defines Burst Rate as:

> ...the highest speed (in megabytes per second) at which data can be transferred from the drive interface (IDE or SCSI for example) to the operating system.

Which begs some questions... e.g. if this is the highest, then how did the bechmarking tool record the 103MB/sec maximum?

And if this really is the true maximum, then where is the bottleneck?  The laptops SATA interface is on an Intel 82801GBM southbridge controller.  When I check in hardware manager, I see that it's driver is iaStor.sys from 2005.  Maybe that's the issue?  I'll look for a newever version, but any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks

---

UPDATE:

Acorting to [this page](http://www.hdtune.com/faq_2.html) on the HDTune website...

> An important parameter of the test is the Burst Rate. This value should always be higher than the maximum transfer rate.
>   A lower value is usually an indication of a configuration problem.

So what might be the configuration problem?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Burst rate == peak recorded by HDTune, Max rate == peak as reported by connector. Bottleneck == the hard disk.

Comment: @John T - Windows XP Pro Sp3

Comment: @ Sathya - Hmm, my previous hard drives always had higher Burst rate than Max rate, so I don't see how that could be the case.